# How to replicate pm.test behaviour in Cypress?

Tags: postman, cypress

In Postman, I am using the `pm.test` function for writing the assertions.

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

I am providing the Test name as `Status code is 200`. I can write multiple test names but How replicate the same behaviour in Cypress.

I tried writing multiple it blocks but `Cy.request` must be inside of `it()` block because of this I am unable to write multiple it blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted each assertion to be a separate test, you could use separate `it` blocks.

```js
it('tests the request status code', () => {
  cy.request('/foo').should((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eql(200);
  });
});

it('tests the request body', () => {
  cy.request('/foo').should((response) => {
    expect(response.body).to.eql('foo');
  });
});
```

Otherwise, if you wanted to make multiple assertions on the same network request, you could just handle that in the callback for the `.should()` command.

```js
it('tests the request', () => {
  cy.request('/foo').should((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eql(200);
    expect(response.body).to.eql('foo');
    ... // other validations
  });
});
```

Comment: I would really like to appreciate for taking your time and answering my question .

But In the above case, For every assertion we have to trigger the request. 

My requirement is that, I have trigger the request only once and then I should add the multiple assertions with the Multiple test names. 

Above case is possible with POSTMAN. In Postman, I am triggering the request only once and then I am writing Lot of assertions with multiple test names. 

I am looking for the similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it. Please use the following approach

```js
var response1;

it('GET /request', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: base_Url,
      }).then((response) => {
        response1 = response
      });
});

it('Validate the Status code', () => {
    
    expect(response1.status).to.eql(200)
});

it('Give your test name', () => {
   use `response1` variable for fetching the response of the request without triggering each and every time.  
});
```

We can use `it()` block as a test block. We can use `it()` block for each every test.